# Horror film about a mummy like creature that goes around killing a bunch of people and making them evil

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I watched this movie in around 2012, This mummy-like creature (or evil spirit) that lives in a two-storey house, and a group of 5 or more or less, people move into it.

The creature then goes on to kill all the people except one or two, but he kills them in strange ways. And after he kills them he does some sort of ritual to make them kill people, and it makes them stay in the house with him. Part of the ritual consists of him cutting them open a little bit then putting some herbs and flowers and random things into the wounds, which makes the spirits of the people stay in the house.

Comment: Were any of the people children, or were they all adults? Also, when you say the people were killed "in strange ways," could you give some specific examples?

Comment: Was the mummy-like creature firm, "solid" or transparent, ghost-like? Were people young or were they a family? Were animated people looking like zombies or some other way? Was it during the daytime or at night ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this movie called [Blood Creek](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0450336/) (2009), where this Nazi has been living off of the blood of people since before WWII and and if something dies he uses magic to animate them and control them. There is a part where the ground-up bones of a skeleton are packed into open wounds.